# Using A Remote with an iOS Application

Tags: ios, unity-game-engine, bluetooth, google-cardboard, virtual-reality

I was following a tutorial video on YouTube on building applications that use a Bluetooth remote for the Google Cardboard. Unfortunately, the video was made specifically for virtual reality on the Android but I use an iPhone6. I created the same app in Unity and ran it on my phone but the remote does not seem to connect to the application. Do I have to do something special to make my remote compatible with my iOS application?

**Additional information:**

I have a SteelSeries Nimbus remote.

The link to the tutorial is as follows: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Vrx57RVTjwI

Comment: Bluetooth or Bluetooth low energy? You should give more details in the question rather than link a tutorial video...

Comment: @Wain Bluetooth low energy, I believe